# How do I prevent the /boot disk space error?

Tags: 14.04, update-manager

I get the "Not enough free disk space" error about once a month during software updates. I'm getting tired of having to manually clear out old kernels every time I get this message.

Is there something I can do to prevent this issue from regularly occurring? I would like to have an automated solution so I don't have to manually remove old kernels every month.

I would think there would be something in place to prevent old unused kernels from accumulating like this.

---

*I know there are a bunch of questions on here on how to clear up some disk space in `/boot` in order to get rid of this error. That is not my question. I have not found any solutions that prevent this error from being a regular issue. I will continue searching while this question is up though, just in case I missed something.*

Comment: The closest thing I've found is [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/RemoveOldKernels#line-28), which is not actually automatic, but is the fastest manual way I've found.

Comment: Well, stop using `/boot` is one possibility.

Comment: Wouldn't that just bloat some other part of my hard drive? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: No, you aren't misunderstanding me. But are all parts of your hard drive significantly restricted in size (<= 500MB)? Or perhaps you are.. What I meant is to stop keeping `/boot` in a separate partition.

Comment: No my main partition is around 500GB. But over time wouldn't  the space taken up by old kernels just keep growing until it's a problem again?

Comment: We're talking ~40MB per kernel. At that rate, it just takes 6 old versions to fill up 250 MB (a typical `/boot`), but you would need 25 old versions to get to 1GB. An `apt-get autoremove` once a month and you'll never get that far.

Comment: @muru Thanks, I'll definitely keep this in mind. I would still like to find a way to automate this though.

Comment: @NGRhodes I don't see how this is a duplicate. That question is asking why autoremove doesn't remove old kernels and how they can get it to do so. I'm asking if there is a way to automate kernel removal so that I don't have to be constantly dealing with it. I'll add an edit to make this more clear.

Comment: You can run `apt-get autoremove` once a month using cron.

Comment: @muru Thanks! That sounds like exactly what I'm looking for. If you post that as an answer I'll mark it as accepted.